# a div block for each button

Tags: javascript, css

There will be 3 buttons on the page when clicking on one of them, a `div` block should appear in the middle of the screen, when clicking on another button, the previous block should disappear and another one will appear in its place.

It turned out to make one block, but a problem arose with several:

```js
$('input').click(function() {
  $('.box').stop(true).animate({
    'top': '100px'
  }, 500);
});
$('#close').click(function() {
  $('.box').stop(true).animate({
    'top': '-100%'
  }, 500);
});
```

```css
.box {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: -100%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -200px;
  color: azure;
  background: rgba(127, 121, 121, 0.5);
  width: 400px;
  height: 200px;
  text-align: center;
}

.box p {
  line-height: 200px;
}

#close {
  float: right;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 30px;
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="box">
  <span id="close">X</span>
  <p>Содержание блока</p>
</div>
<input type="button" value="Показать окошко">
```

Comment: you want to make it dynamic or there will be fixed 3 divs?

Comment: will be dynamically on pages from 3 to 15 blocks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this. have an `id` for each box and have a `data-target` for each button that must be the target box and then use these to show and hide the box.

```js
$('input').click(function($event) {
  $('.box').stop(true).animate({
    'top': '-100%'
  }, 500);
  $('#' + $event.target.getAttribute('data-target')).stop(true).animate({
    'top': '100px'
  }, 500);
});
$('.close').click(function($event) {
  $('#' + $event.target.getAttribute('data-target')).stop(true).animate({
    'top': '-100%'
  }, 500);
});
```

```css
.box {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: -100%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -200px;
  color: azure;
  background: rgba(127, 121, 121, 0.5);
  width: 400px;
  height: 200px;
  text-align: center;
}

.box p {
  line-height: 200px;
}

.close {
  float: right;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 30px;
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.js"></script>

<div class="box" id="one">
  <span data-target="one" class="close">X</span>
  <p>Содержание блока 1</p>
</div>
<input data-target="one" type="button" value="1">

<div class="box" id="two">
  <span data-target="two" class="close">X</span>
  <p>Содержание блока 2</p>
</div>
<input data-target="two" type="button" value="2">

<div class="box" id="three">
  <span data-target="three" class="close">X</span>
  <p>Содержание блока 3</p>
</div>
<input data-target="three" type="button" value="3">
```

Let me know if you still face issues.

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Over here it works fine.. if you click 1 first block opens.. now if you click 2 second block opens and the first one closes.. Now if you click 3 second one closes and 3rd one opens.. Thats what you looking for right?

Comment: The problem has come to light when there are a lot of blocks, they do not appear in the visible part of the screen. get out a little from above

Comment: Can you show me how.. I mean a demo kind of where i can see the issue happennig.